# Django Dynamic Scraper STANDARD(UPDATE) implies mandatory elements?

Tags: python, django, scrapy

### Problem:

In Django Dynamic Scraper, it seems as if setting a scraped object class' scraped_obj_attr type to STANDARD(UPDATE) results in the element being considered mandatory, and the spider will drop the result if it cannot get data for that element. When I change the type to STANDARD, the spider no longer drops the result when it doesn't get that element. This is undesirable, because I'd like to have optional elements that are updated if they *do* happen to exist.

### Checked:

I have confirmed that the database contains "f" for the corresponding row's "Mandatory" column in the dynamic_scraper_scraperelem table. The table in Django admin also shows no checkmark for Mandatory for that element. I also read all the related documentation and Q&A threads I could find on the topic. Everything else about DDS/my Django installation seems to be working great.

I dug into the code a bit and found this in dynamic_scraper.pipelines, ValidationPipeline class. Line 5 seems relevant - perhaps this "if" condition is being met unexpectedly?

```
class ValidationPipeline(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        url_elem = spider.scraper.get_detail_page_url_elem()
        url_name = url_elem.scraped_obj_attr.name
        if url_name in item and item[url_name][0:6] == 'DOUBLE':
            mandatory_elems = spider.scraper.get_standard_update_elems()
        else:
            mandatory_elems = spider.scraper.get_mandatory_scrape_elems()
        for elem in mandatory_elems:
            if not elem.scraped_obj_attr.name in item or\
                (elem.scraped_obj_attr.name in item and not    item[elem.scraped_obj_attr.name]):
                spider.log("Mandatory elem " + elem.scraped_obj_attr.name + " missing!", log.ERROR)
                raise DropItem()
        ...
```

### Question:

Is this expected behavior?

### Configuration:

Ubuntu 12.04.1 32-bit, system packages for Python 2.7.3, Postgresql 9.1, and Supervisor. Nginx is the latest stable from PPA. The spider is being run manually for testing: "scrapy crawl my_spider -a id=1 -a do_action=yes".

my_scraper.scraper.settings.py:

```
import sys
import os.path

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path = sys.path + [os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '../../..'), os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '../..')]

from django.core.management import setup_environ
import mysite.settings
setup_environ(mysite.settings)

BOT_NAME = 'mybot'
BOT_VERSION = '1.0'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['dynamic_scraper.spiders', 'my_scraper.scraper',]
USER_AGENT = '%s/%s' % (BOT_NAME, BOT_VERSION)

ITEM_PIPELINES = [
    'dynamic_scraper.pipelines.DjangoImagesPipeline',
    'dynamic_scraper.pipelines.ValidationPipeline',
    'my_scraper.scraper.pipelines.DjangoWriterPipeline',
]

IMAGES_STORE = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '../thumbnails')

DSCRAPER_LOG_ENABLED = True
DSCRAPER_LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO'
DSCRAPER_LOG_LIMIT = 5

DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 2
CONCURRENT_SPIDERS = 1
```

virtualenv:

```
$ pip freeze
Django==1.4.3
Fabric==1.5.1
PIL==1.1.7
Pillow==1.7.8
Scrapy==0.14.4
South==0.7.6
Twisted==12.3.0
amqp==1.0.6
amqplib==1.0.2
anyjson==0.3.3
argparse==1.2.1
billiard==2.7.3.19
celery==2.5.3
django-appconf==0.5
django-celery==2.5.5
django-dynamic-scraper==0.2.3
django-forms-bootstrap==2.0.3.post1
django-kombu==0.9.4
django-picklefield==0.3.0
django-user-accounts==1.0b7
gevent==0.13.8
greenlet==0.4.0
gunicorn==0.17.1
httplib2==0.7.7
kombu==2.1.8
lxml==3.1beta1
metron==1.0
numpy==1.6.2
oauth2==1.5.211
paramiko==1.9.0
pinax-theme-bootstrap==2.2.2
pinax-theme-bootstrap-account==1.0b2
pinax-utils==1.0b1.dev3
psycopg2==2.4.6
pyOpenSSL==0.13
pycrypto==2.6
python-dateutil==1.5
pytz==2012d
six==1.2.0
w3lib==1.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
zope.interface==4.0.3
```

Comment: Setting up a couple of additional environments now; I'll make sure I can reproduce the behavior there as well.